# In a solidly grounded wye service, is an open neutral an emergency?

Tags: electrical, safety

Open neutrals in 120/240V North American split phase services are considered an emergency due to the fire and equipment damage hazard unbalanced legs pose.  However, there are residential buildings (both single and multiple unit) that use three phase wye electrical services instead of split phase.

In these setups, is an open service neutral still an electrical emergency worthy of an immediate callout to the electrical utility, or is there something about three phase wye power vs. split phase that makes an open neutral less of a hazard?

Comment: More dangerous perhaps in commercial buildings with excessive reactive power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the open neutral is still dangerous in that situation for the same reason, the voltage on one leg will rise as high as 208V, and current will travel on the grounds.